# ActionScript - Array.sortOn() For Non-English Data?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, sorting, non-english

this is an array of objects that i want to alphabetize:

```
var streets:Array = new Array();
streets.push({name:"Édouard-Montpetit"});
streets.push({name:"Alexandre de Sève"});
streets.push({name:"Van Horne"});
streets.push({name:"Atwater"});
```

now i'll sort my array:

```
streets.sortOn("name", Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);

//Sorted
Alexandre de Sève
Atwater
Van Horne
Édouard-Montpetit
```

the accent above the E in Édouard-Montpetit, and any other first letter with a non-english accent is sorted after Z.

any ideas how i can sort this correctly?  i do not have access to the named data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is late, but for anyone going through this answer, you could pass a [Collator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS9b644acd4ebe59998b99a90125fc4fecfb-7ff8.html)
object to the Array.sort() method. A simple example from the documentation:

```
 var words:Array = new  Array("coté", "côte"); 
 var sorter:Collator = new Collator("fr-FR", CollatorMode.SORTING); 
 words.sort(sorter.compare); 
 trace(words);// côte,coté
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it with `sortOn`, as there's no way to tell flash to use a particular collaction for sorting text (at least, not that I'm aware of).

However, you could use `sort` and a custom sort function.

In this sort function, basically you want to strip all accents and do a case insensitive comparation. Replacing diacritics is easy and after that, you can safely use `<` and `>` for comparing the strings. A sort function is called by sort with two of the items to be sorted at a time. It should return a negative number if the first passed items sorts first , a possitive number if the second comes first and 0 if they sort equal.

```
function sortText(obj1:Object,obj2:Object):int {
    var a:String = replaceDiacritics(obj1.name);
    var b:String = replaceDiacritics(obj2.name);

    if(a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else if(b < a) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function replaceDiacritics(str:String):String {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    str = str.replace(/á/g,"a");
    str = str.replace(/é/g,"e");
    str = str.replace(/í/g,"i");
    str = str.replace(/ó/g,"o");
    str = str.replace(/ú/g,"u");

    str = str.replace(/à/g,"a");
    str = str.replace(/è/g,"e");
    str = str.replace(/ì/g,"i");
    str = str.replace(/ò/g,"o");
    str = str.replace(/ù/g,"u");

    return str;
}

streets.sort(sortText);
```

A couple of notes about this. I know this method won't work for Spanish, as you have `ñ`, which is considered a letter on its own (not a regular `n` with a funny mark) and comes after `n` and before `o`. So, it's not possible to just replace accents and do a `<` /  `>` compare. I think this is not a problem in French, but I could be wrong (not sure how `Ç` / `ç` is considered for sort purposes, for instance). Also, note that I haven't replaced all possible diacritics, so you'd want to add circumflexes (^) and umlauts (¨) to `replaceDiacritics` as necessary.

**Edit**

For a table based approach you could try something like the following. Each letter is assigned a number that reflects the sort order. As long as you can assume that any letter will have an absolute sort order (that is, context won't change how this works, which is not the case on some languages), it should give you good results.

Out of laziness, I built the table with a loop and just did what was neccesary to put "Ñ" between "n" and "o". I'm not considering any diacritics for sorting purposes, so they have the same value than their unaccented counterpart. But you could change this table as neccesary. Also, this table probably should be hardcoded for the required locale, but this code is just to give you an idea of how you could do this, not a full implementation (and it's probably not entirely correct from a purist perspective, but I think it could do the job). Also, in case we find a character that is not mapped, I'm falling back to its code point to determine how it sorts.

var sortTable:Object = buildSortTable();

```
function buildSortTable():Object {
    var sortTable:Object = {};
    var char:String;
    var offset:int = 0;
    for(var i:int = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        char = String.fromCharCode(i);
        if(char == "Ñ" || char == "ñ") {
            offset--;
            continue;
        }
        sortTable[char] = i + offset;

        if(char == "N") {
            sortTable["Ñ"] = sortTable["N"] + 1;
            offset++;
        }
        if(char == "n") {
            sortTable["ñ"] = sortTable["n"] + 1;
            offset++;
        }

    }

    sortTable["Á"] = sortTable["À"] = sortTable["Ä"] = sortTable["Â"] = sortTable["A"];
    sortTable["É"] = sortTable["È"] = sortTable["Ë"] = sortTable["Ê"] = sortTable["E"];
    sortTable["Í"] = sortTable["Ì"] = sortTable["Ï"] = sortTable["Î"] = sortTable["I"];
    sortTable["Ó"] = sortTable["Ò"] = sortTable["Ö"] = sortTable["Ô"] = sortTable["O"];
    sortTable["Ú"] = sortTable["Ì"] = sortTable["Ü"] = sortTable["Û"] = sortTable["U"];

    sortTable["á"] = sortTable["à"] = sortTable["ä"] = sortTable["â"] = sortTable["a"];
    sortTable["é"] = sortTable["è"] = sortTable["ë"] = sortTable["ê"] = sortTable["e"];
    sortTable["í"] = sortTable["ì"] = sortTable["ï"] = sortTable["î"] = sortTable["i"];
    sortTable["ó"] = sortTable["ò"] = sortTable["ö"] = sortTable["ô"] = sortTable["o"];
    sortTable["ú"] = sortTable["ù"] = sortTable["ü"] = sortTable["û"] = sortTable["u"];

    return sortTable;
}

function sortText(obj1:Object,obj2:Object):int {

    var a:String = obj1.name.toLowerCase();
    var b:String = obj2.name.toLowerCase();

    var len_a:int = a.length;
    var len_b:int = b.length;

    var char_a:String;
    var char_b:String;

    var val_a:Number;
    var val_b:Number;

    for(var i = 0; i < len_a && i < len_b; i++) {
        char_a = a.charAt(i);
        char_b = b.charAt(i);

        val_a = sortTable[char_a];
        val_b = sortTable[char_b];
        //  this is just in case we have a letter that we haven't mapped...
        //  let's fall back to using its code point
        if(isNaN(val_a)) {
            val_a = char_a.charCodeAt(0);
        }
        if(isNaN(val_b)) {
            val_b = char_b.charCodeAt(0);
        }

        if(val_a < val_b) {
            return -1;
        } else if(val_a > val_b) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    // both strings are equal so far; so the sorter one (if any) must sort first
    if(len_a < len_b) {
        return -1;
    } else if(len_a > len_b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is very helpful.  thank you very much.  my tests show that "ç", and all other diacritics in french are sorted after "z".  of interest, l'accent aigu: é is always sorted before l'accent grave: è.  i wonder if this exclusion of language diacritics is by design.  perhaps this should be reported as a bug or feature request.

Comment: also, sorting graphemes, like æ and œ, don't sort correctly.  but its probably overkill to include those anyway.

Comment: No problem. I think the above method could be good enough, but it's not perfect, for sure. Perhaps it could be tweaked for better results, but that requires knowing how sorting works in French (which I don't know). If ç must sort after z, then you could just not replace it in the replace diacritics function. If æ and œ are equivalent for sorting purposes to ae and oe, then I think you could add them in the replace function (so æ is converted to ae). As for diacritics order, if it's important that á comes before à, then you should probably change the code to use a table based approach.

Comment: (cont). I know in Spanish this is not crucial, as we only have the acute accent and ü. For instance, probably "sabia" (sap or wise [feminine]) comes before "sabía" ([he/she/it/formal singular you] knew). But in practice, this is not a real problem (again, in Spanish, from the perspective of a native speaker, not an expert in sorting, collations, etc). I don't think there's a bug in the player. It's just a binary sort, so the characters are sorted based on their numeric code points. It'd be nice, however, that you could set a collation so the results are more meaningful for non English locales.

Comment: @TheDarkInI1978. I added some code to show you how you could implement a table based sort.

Comment: would it be faster to check for the presents of characters before automatically replacing them?  if (str.indexOf("á") != -1) str = str.replace(/á/g,"a");, etc. ?

Comment: @TheDarkInI1978. I guess the only way to know for sure is profiling it. But my "gut feeling" is that it won't be faster in case there's nothing to replace and it would be slower if you actually have to replace some letter. If there's nothing to replace you have a loop through all chars (with `indexOf`). If there's something to replace, the loop runs until it finds the first occurrence and then you have a full loop to actually replace the char. So you have in the best case a full loop, which is about the same as replacing directly.

Comment: yeah, besides not really being able to accurately determine what's faster, since the sort data will vary, i guess the difference in speed would be negligible.